# Elasticsearch query with fields not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i am new to elastic search  database, When i want to search with fields  I am getting following error. Help me to solve this.

```
Trace: [query_parsing_exception] [filtered] query does not support [fields], with { index=test_database line=1 col=58 }
```

My Code to search:

```
 client.search({
  index: 'test_database',
    body: {
      query : {
           match_all : {},
          fields: ["price","brand"]

      },

    }
})
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid query. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with your query?

Comment: I just updated my question. please look at once. , I want to select only price and brand from my object. but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. As, match all query doesn't support fields.

```
client.search({
   index: 'test_database',
      body: {
          fields: ["price","brand"],
          query : {
              match_all : {}
      }

    }
})
```

Comment: Or you can place the fields after the query block.